# Что означает фраза «Forefront TMG denied the specified uniform» в логах?

Tags: proxy

При попытке подключиться к сайту через корпоративный прокси выдаётся сообщение:

```
SocketError: 403: Forbidden (Forefront TMG denied the specific uniform resource locator)
```

Что это означает - сайт меня заблокировал по IP или прокси не даёт подключаться?